# Accessing directory reveals Apache port used for VirtualHost

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, virtualhost

I have small project and discovered little bug.
Whenever accessing http://example.com/images (without ending directory slash) I get redirected to http://example.com:port/images
How would I remove it?
My HTACCESS currently is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is probably happening because of your Apache server config, or VirtualHost config.

Comment: Everything is set by default. I have modified ports.conf with Listen rules for each VirtualHost and VirtualHost's is like this: http://pastebin.com/7vfjZnyE

Comment: @user3083231 Please post the code here rather than linking to it. Also, post all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Show the virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a ServerName in your virtualhost. It will be used as the basis for self-referential links.